# SQLite3::CantOpenException: unable to open database file while testing Ruby Gem

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rails-engines, travis-ci

I'm running into this error message while testing a gem on travis:

```
SQLite3::CantOpenException: unable to open database file
```

I'm not even hitting the database in any of the tests, which is weird. Looks like the backtrace points a finger at fixtures, though I don't have any fixtures. Even if I did, the db is sqlite3...shouldn't it be able to be created on the fly?

You can see the build output here: http://travis-lite.com/schneems/maildown/jobs/9662299

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your [`test_helper.rb`](https://github.com/schneems/maildown/blob/master/test/test_helper.rb#L12-15) file includes this

```
# Load fixtures from the engine
if ActiveSupport::TestCase.method_defined?(:fixture_path=)
  ActiveSupport::TestCase.fixture_path = File.expand_path("../fixtures", __FILE__)
end
```

Since you don't have fixtures, I'm guessing this is what's causing the trouble. You probably want to remove those lines?

You also don't have a `/db` folder in your project, try adding that to see if it fixes the build.

Comment: Yep, the missing /db folder caused the problem, had to checkin a .gitignore file to it to get it to register in the git repo

Comment: +1 for the missing /db folder, which is the real solution for the author, unless I'm misunderstanding